# MySQL - INSERT SELECT with a default value for one column

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm making an `INSERT ... SELECT` query in MySQL but i don't know how to add a default value for one column.

This is my current query:

```
INSERT INTO book (id, name, descripcion, status)
SELECT cb_id, cb_name, cb_descripcion FROM current_books WHERE cb_id = 34;
```

I need to set the value for `status column` to 2. How can i add it to my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO book (id, name, descripcion, status)
    SELECT cb_id, cb_name, cb_descripcion, 2 FROM current_books WHERE cb_id = 34;
```

Just select "2", I don't see any problem here :)